# Keras : Fine tune ELMo embedding with BilSTM keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to build model with ELMo embedding with Bi-lstm in Keras

ELMo layer looks like this:

```
class ElmoEmbeddingLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.dimensions = 1024
        self.trainable=True
        super(ElmoEmbeddingLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.elmo = hub.Module('https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2', trainable=self.trainable,
                               name="{}_module".format(self.name))

        self.trainable_weights += K.tf.trainable_variables(scope="^{}_module/.*".format(self.name))
        super(ElmoEmbeddingLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        result = self.elmo(K.squeeze(K.cast(x, tf.string), axis=1),
                      as_dict=True,
                      signature='default',
                      )['default']

        return result

    def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
        return K.not_equal(inputs, '--PAD--')

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.dimensions)
```

Since Bilstm need 3d input and output from elmo is [batch, 1024 ] so I expended one dim and it becomes [batch, 1, 1024 ] Now I am feeding this to Bi-Lstm

```
input_text = layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype="string")
embeddingss = ElmoEmbeddingLayer()(input_text)
expand_dim  = K.expand_dims(embeddingss,1)
lstm_o    = Bidirectional(LSTM(256))(expand_dim)
```

Now when I am passing lstm_output to dense layer :

```
pred      = layers.Dense(22, activation='sigmoid')(lstm_o)
model     = Model(inputs=[input_text], outputs=pred)
```

I am getting this error:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'
> ```

I checked and found this error is because I am directly using Keras backend features, the solution is to use Lambda layer to wrap that feature so I tried this:

```
lambda_con      = Lambda(lambda x: K.expand_dims(x,1))
layer_output    = lambda_con(embeddingss)

lstm_o    = Bidirectional(LSTM(256))(layer_output)
```

But then I am getting this error:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'layer'
> ```

How to feed ELMo embedding output to Keras Bi-Lstm?

Thank you !